# Decentralized File Storage on Ethereum white paper

Tags: dapp-development, dapps, storage, white-paper

I am reading white paper of Ethereum, and I am confused by this example of the ***Section. Decentralized File Storage***, which is part of the ***Section. Applications***:

> The key underpinning piece of such a device would be what we have termed the "decentralized Dropbox contract". This contract works as follows. First, one splits the desired data up into blocks, encrypting each block for privacy, and builds a Merkle tree out of it. One then makes a contract with the rule that, every N blocks, the contract would pick a random index in the Merkle tree (using the previous block hash, accessible from contract code, as a source of randomness), and give X ether to the ﬁrst entity to supply a transaction with a simpliﬁed payment veriﬁcation-like proof of ownership of the block at that particular index in the tree. When a user wants to re-download their ﬁle, they can use a micropayment channel protocol (eg. pay 1 szabo per 32 kilobytes) to recover the ﬁle; the most fee-efﬁcient approach is for the payer not to publish the transaction until the end, instead replacing the transaction with a slightly more lucrative one with the same nonce after every 32 kilobytes.

Especially the long sentence in the middle:

> *One then makes a contract with the rule that, every N blocks, the contract would pick a random index in the Merkle tree (using the previous block hash, accessible from contract code, as a source of randomness), and give X ether to the ﬁrst entity to supply a transaction with a simpliﬁed payment veriﬁcation-like proof of ownership of the block at that particular index in the tree.*

Can someone explain more of it?

Comment: seems like it's describing the swarm storage protocol you can find more details here [https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/08/16/secret-sharing-erasure-coding-guide-aspiring-dropbox-decentralizer/](https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/08/16/secret-sharing-erasure-coding-guide-aspiring-dropbox-decentralizer/)